# Spring batch inserting relationships

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am inserting records from xml into a table with many foreign keys. From the XML data there may be a foreign relationship that does not exist yet, so i will need to insert it prior to inserting main entity.

Ex.

```
<person>
   <name>p1</name>
   <school>XYZ School</school>
<person>
```

My JDBCBatchItemWriter sql would be:

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, SCHOOL_ID) VALUES (:name, (SELECT ID FROM SCHOOLS WHERE SCHOOL_NAME = :school));
```

Do i need a separate job step to insert each relationship prior to inserting the main entity? I have looked for examples with relational data and everything i find seems to be the simplistic case where the foreign keys will already exist.

Solution:
Ended up making a step to create a HashMap> of all the foreign object that i need to make. Then inject this into the next step which does an insert if the object does not exist yet. Might need a better solution than using an in memory HashMap, but seems to work for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to address this.  The question really is about how they get loaded.  Do you need to do a check to see if they exist first?  This check can have a big hit on performance if done needlessly.  The most performant way to accomplish this is through a separate step assuming you can just blindly insert them in that earlier step.

Comment: Hello Michael. Yes, I would need to check if they already existed. So for each foreign key i would have a step to iterate though the file, check if it already exists in the ItemProcessor and then insert if the foreign object does not exist yet?

Comment: I'd recommend going through the file once and keeping track of what foreign keys need to be created and do that all at once if possible.  The fewer times you need to check the db for the key's existence and the fewer times you need to iterate over a file, the better the job will perform.  I'd need to know more about the data to go any further in depth.